# Real time data update framework

Tags: c#, .net

Am developing client-server application for updating real time chart. Can anyone suggest me any framework/concepts for developing .Net based Server application (so that server will respond to clients very faster)

Client is not a web-based one (it will be MatLab client application). And each client will establish individual connection with server. Server needs to respond to individual client in real time.

Comment: can you be more specific?. Are you looking at a Web application or Forms/WPF application?

Comment: @SridharVenkat doesn't matter, SignalR can work with Web Browser as well as applications..

Comment: Client is not a web-based one (it will be MatLab client application). And each client will establish individual connection with server. Server needs to respond to individual client in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into signalR. It's a push framework that lets you maintain long running connections between client and server which enables the server to push updates to the client.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is absolutely awesome here, and with OWIN you can host SignalR within a console app even. However, if you are not interested in learning a new framework, and are not using asp.net, you might want to use a regular Socket library provided with .NET and go from there.